# Plotting a function on a specified domain

Tags: matlab, plot, ode45

I am trying to plot the solution of a system of ODEs.
The code is:

```
  tspan = [0 10];
  z0 = [0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01];
  [t,z] = ode45(@(t,z) odefun3(t,z), tspan, z0);
  plot(z(:,3))
```

Why the output is plotted on the interval [0,60] and not on [0,10], as in the code ?
[image]

Comment: `@(t,z)odefun(t,z)` is equivalent to `@odefun`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, by adding the first variable under the `plot` command: `plot(t,z(:,3))`.